# php get specific data from the same column in all row

Tags: php, mysql

i have a php question,
how can i get all the data from the same column from all row in a mysql table.

Table name : user
Here's my table structure:
name 
url

How can i use php to get all the data in URL column from each row?
(P/S i have my connection to database established , just not sure the musql query for this)

Thanks and have a nice day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This really is extremely basic stuff and you could have found this anywhere, it's even in the PHP manual. But alas, here you go.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT url FROM user");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result){
   echo $row['url'].'\n';
}
```

Please read up on some basic stuff to avoid asking these kind of questions: http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql

Comment: True, matter of habit for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "select url from user";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo $row['url'] . '<br>';
}
```